# Trying to uninstall MySQL connector, getting - 'Extensions' is not a valid short file name

Tags: windows-7, mysql, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall MySql connector (6.3.6) and I keep getting - 'Extensions' is not a valid short file name.
Googling made me look for 'Extensions' in the registry, but nothing was found.
What is this error, and how do I uninstall the connector?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: @Daniel - I consider thanking people for their time good manners, as do SOME of the people here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64649/is-writing-will-upvote-appropriate (regarding "thanks in advance", which is similar). Anyway there are opinions both ways, but editing that out is unjustified IMO.

Comment: Unlike others, I wouldn't have edited simply for the [hi/bye](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) parts of your question. But since I changed the title and tags anyway, I didn't think it'd hurt.